# Maximum change in entropy when conditioning on an event

Tags: conditional-probability, entropy, information-theory, conditioning, conditional-entropy

Let $P_{XYZ}$ be the joint distribution of discrete RVs $X,Y,Z$ where $Z$ is binary-valued. Let $Q_{XY}=P_{XY|Z=0}$, i.e. the distribution of $XY$ conditioned on $Z=0$. Are there lower/upper bounds on $H(X|Y)_P$ in terms of $H(X|Y)_Q$ and the probability $P[Z=0]$? (Mainly I would need an upper bound, but I would also be interested to know if some lower bound can be found.)

A somewhat similar question was asked at [Confusion about conditional entropy when conditioning on another event](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/449907/confusion-about-conditional-entropy-when-conditioning-on-another-event), but was more restricted (the conditioning event was determined by $Y$ alone) and was mostly focused on the "lower bound" side of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Going to change your notation to use more standard $H(X|Y)$ to represent $H(X|Y)_P$ and $H(X | Y, Z=0)$ to represent $H(X | Y)_Q$

\begin{align} H(X|Y) &\geq H(X | Y, Z) \quad \textrm{(conditioning reduces entropy)} \\ &= H(X|Y, Z=0) Pr(Z=0) + H(X | Y, Z=1) Pr(Z=1) \end{align}

Note that the second term on the RHS is non-negative so depending on your use case, a loose bound would be $H(X|Y) \geq H(X | Y, Z=0)Pr(Z=0)$

Comment: Unfortunately, the conditioning-reduces-entropy inequality is in the wrong direction here; what you have is a lower bound on $H(X|Y)$ (similar to that in the linked answer), not an upper bound...

Comment: My mistake.  I've edited the answer.  In general, $H(X|Y, Z=0)$ can vary arbitrarily.  For example, we can have $Y = \mathrm{Bernoulli}(1)$ if $Z = 0$ (i.e., $Y$ is deterministic) and $Y=\mathrm{Bern}(0.5)$ if $Z = 1$.  Alternatively, we can switch the indices of $Z$ so $Y$ is deterministic if $Z=1$.  $H(X|Y, Z=0)$ can be larger or smaller than $H(X|Y)$ but the average value $H(X|Y, Z) \leq H(X|Y)$

Comment: I think that construction does not preclude the possibility of an upper bound on $H(X|Y)$ that depends on _both_ $H(X|Y;Z=0)$ and $P[Z=0]$ though, as stated in the question. For instance, in the case of _min_-entropy it is known that $H_\mathrm{min}(X|Y) \leq H_\mathrm{min}(X|Y;Z=0) + \log(1/P[Z=0])$, so while it is true that $H_\mathrm{min}(X|Y)$ and $H_\mathrm{min}(X|Y;Z=0)$ can be sort of "arbitrarily different", it turns out that the amount of arbitrariness is at most $\log(1/P[Z=0])$, so to speak. I was basically wondering if something in this vein could hold for Shannon entropy as well.